# Can I change the 'window.location' property inside a Bookmarklet and then continue doing things on the new document?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, wizard

I want know if you can guide to users for a series of steps that imply visit different web pages using actions inside a Bookmarklet. What I want is a kind of Wizard or automated actions cross web pages.

Comment: No. js is on the client, it has no special control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You partially can, if you open the new pages inside an iframe. However, you won't be able to modifying the content of the webpages anymore, but just modifying the url of the iframe, and going through different websites (like a kind of slideshow).

Notice that if you're the owner of the pages, you can use [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage) to interact with them, even if they're in different domains.

Or, you could do a "tunneling" on server side, and inject each team you got the page back with the JS you need.

But probably the cleanest approach if you're not the owner of the pages is just create a simple restartless add-on for the browsers you want to support.

Answer (score 1):

Afraid not. What you're describing would actually be very **dangerous**. If there were any **malicious code** in the bookmarklet, it would have access to every site you are logged into, email, amazon etc. Some pseudocode for an attack could look like this:

```
window.location = "www.gmail.com";
ajax.post("www.gmail.com/deleteAllMail");
window.location = "www.amazon.com";
ajax.post("www.amazon.com/buyReallyExpensiveStuff");
```